# weird predictions with lstm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to predict the failure of a machine using the data recorded during last breakdown. For that i decided to use LSTM from keras. I would like to know how the `model.predict()` actually works.I used the 90% of the data given to me for training in order to predict the rest. The model predicts really 'good' when i gave the actually data for `model.predict()`

[image: prediction using 10% real data]

But when i gave a numpy array containing numbers from 1 to 374300, in increasing order.

[image: prediction using numpy array]

Could this be a case of overfitting?

Comment: Train your network on increasing sequences of numbers.  Should do fine. :)

Comment: No one knows what you mean when you say you "gave a numpy array containing numbers from 1 to 374300" Can you provide some context?

Comment: I used the following code for prediction, which gave me that 2nd plot. `pred_list = np.arange(x_test.shape[0]* x_test.shape[1]).reshape((x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
predictions = model.predict(pred_list)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)`   Here shape of x_test is (7486, 50, 1), which contains the real data.